# android.graphics.Bitmap on iOS

Tags: android, ios, bitmap

I'm migrating an Android application to iOS.

On Android I have an `android.graphics.Bitmap` object and I don't know which object can I use on iOS.

I thought I can use `CGBitmapContext` or `UIImage`. And on the book Learn Objective-C for Java Developers, I haven't found anything useful.

On Android, first I have to created with a `size`, that I can use this `Bitmap` to get a JPEG version of it or I can draw some pixels on it.

**What do you recommend me?**

Comment: How are you using `Bitmap` on Android. You can initialize a UIImage using from raw pixel information using `initWithData:` if you don't require it to be mutable.

Comment: @Benoit I have updated my question with more details about how I use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best resource on how to do this is going to be Apple's Drawing and Printing Guide, specifically, [Creating New Images Using Bitmap Graphics Contexts](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/HandlingImages/Images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH13-SW8).

Once you go through the steps listed in the tutorial (and perform [all the necessary drawing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007533-SW1)) and you get a reference to a `UIImage`, you'll want to use [`UIImageJPEGRepresentation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImageJPEGRepresentation) to save the result as a JPEG.

Answer (score 1):

The framework you need to use is called `Core Graphics`. The framework is different from Android - more low level and much more powerful.

Some interesting classes and functions:
`CGImageRef` - represents an image
`CGContextRef` - represents a drawable context
`CGBitmapContext` - a context backed up with raw byte data - you can draw there using context functions or set the color value directly by accessing the bytes.

You can get `CGImageRef` from an `UIImage`, you can also draw `CGImageRef` into `CGBitmapContext` or draw `UIImage` directly into context (`[UIImage draw...]`).

These classes/functions should be enough for you to start googling/searching the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , u can use UIImage or CGImage...

UIImage can thought object oriented wrapper of CGImage....
But as u are from  java background i would suggest that u go with UIImage...

CGBitmapContext is totally different thing.. I thought of it as canvas where u do some drawing and save all what u have drawn as an image..

If u are still confused.. i would ask u to make ur question little clear... i am unable to get what your are trying to achieve..